# How to mock a method that takes a property expression ie Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to mock out a repository method with the signature:

```
Task<Model> FindByIdAsync<TProperty>(Guid id, Expression<Func<Model, TProperty>> include);
```

(The `include` expression is used to include a dependent object on the queried object)

I don't care what the property expression is so I'm trying to use `It.IsAny<something>` but I can't find the right format for the `something`

I've got as far as:

```
mockRepo.Setup(p => p.FindByIdAsync<object>( mockCall.Id, It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Call, object>>>() )).ReturnsAsync(mockObj);
```

but that doesn't match my code which looks like:

```
var m = await _modelRepo.FindByIdAsync( someId, m => m.SomePropertyToInclude );
```

What is the correct way to mock out this method?

Comment: Have you tried: `It.IsAny<Expression<It.IsAnyType>>()` or `It.IsAny<Expression<Func<It.IsAnyType, It.IsAnyType >>()`?

Comment: There's also this dunno if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61322568/491907

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! `p.FindByIdAsync<It.IsAnyType>( mockObj.Id, It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Model, It.IsAnyType>>>() )).ReturnsAsync(mockObj);` worked perfectly.

Comment: no prob! `It.IsAnyType` is a *relatively* new thing. I only learned of it recently but it's been around for two years

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 please write up an answer and I'll accept it